# CSS Grid System for 1003px Width base

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

does anybody know any css grid system with Base 980px Grid and Base 1003 Grid? I used to use skeleton but is Base 960 Grid Max.

Thanks.

Comment: Why this number? Are you worried about causing scroll bars with 1024-wide monitors? (almost 20% of users)

Comment: http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

960.gs has a generator. http://grids.heroku.com/

Column width of 50, 17 columns, 9 gutter width gives you a 1003px grid. Not sure why you'd want one, though.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this one: http://www.pagecolumn.com/grid_layout_generator.htm
you can create your own grid yourself.